# OpenGL App not setting cursor position appropriately

Tags: opengl, c++, sfml, glfw

I have written a small application using OpenGL, and have implemented some rudimentary camera controls. Unfortunately, I cannot get the application to set my cursor position correctly. The cursor is never set to where I tell it to go, so my application just reacts to where the cursor is on my entire screen.

I first attempted to use GLFW, and when I saw that I couldn't set the cursor appropriately, I decided to try SFML. Neither one works.

I'm on an Arch Linux install with a Gnome desktop. I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now to no avail.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
sf::Vector2i cursor_pos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window);
sf::Mouse::setPosition(sf::Vector2i(1280/2, 720/2), *window);
```

This gets called every frame inside a function that messes with some matrices.

I also set the cursor position at initialization.

Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that these functions use window local coordinates?

Comment: Yes, and I believe that's what I want. I want the cursor to lock to the middle of the application window.

Comment: Just making sure your application window is hard coded as 1280x720. btw, you might consider explicitly writing `window->getSize() / 2` to be clear.

Comment: It is hard coded yeah, just to test it out. I've tried it with variables and it didn't change anything. It doesn't lock to the application at all. I am free to move the cursor all over my desktop.

Comment: Make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and if it doesn't work on your machine, one of us can test it on another machine.

Comment: @MickLH it turns out it was an issue with Gnome using Wayland, which has bad support for cursors as of now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Man! I'm sorry I didn't go with my gut earlier, I thought it might be your desktop environment :P

Comment: @MickLH I suspected that as well. It wasn't until I built on my Windows desktop that I realized that was probably the issue. Got it working on regular Gnome after that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a problem with the way Wayland works. My install of Gnome was defaulting to Wayland, instead of x, and Wayland doesn't do a good job of capturing the cursor within a window.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I'm using Arch Linux, Gnome 3, and Wayland with SDL 2 and this behavior seems to work fine, so it might just be difficulties with GLFW and SFML and Wayland. I wouldn't expect users to change from using Wayland to using X11. Wayland is the future for all Gnome users.